# How can I migrate DynamoDB tables to Global DynamoDB tables with minimum downtime?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

AWS is not allow to convert existing DynamoDB tables to Global DynamoDB Tables. So I need to write some code or find already existing tool to do it.
The existed tables has a lot data, because of it export-import process will  take a long time, and downtime it is not an option.

I have an approximate plan of action, to do migration:

1. Create global tables
2. Change application logic to start write in global tables. When request come to read data first try global tables, if there is no data - when read normal tables.
3. Copy data from normal tables to global tables.
4. Change application logic again to write and read only from global tables.
5. Remove normal tables.

I'm wondering if someone did a similar migration? How do you simplify read from two tables (global and normal)? Is there exists any plugin/lib/wrapper for boto, or pynamodb, or other lib to do this? 
Or you did migration using other method, please share it.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://engineering.opsgenie.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-dynamodb-global-tables-952d020d9834

Answer (score 2):

As of November 2019 it is possible to convert existing DynamoDB tables to Global Tables without data loss.

> "Starting today, you can convert your existing DynamoDB tables to
>   global tables with a few clicks in the AWS Management Console, or
>   using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI), or the Amazon DynamoDB
>   API. Previously, only empty tables could be converted to global
>   tables. You had to guess your regional usage of a table at the time
>   you created it. Now you can go global, or you can extend existing
>   global tables to additional regions at any time."

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-convert-your-single-region-amazon-dynamodb-tables-to-global-tables/

To convert a DynamoDB table to Global Tables in the AWS console:

1. Navigate to your DynamoDB table in the AWS console.
2. Select the Global Tables tab.
3. If prompted to enable Streams, enable Streams. Streams are required for Global Tables.
4. Click Add Region to add a Global Table and select a region.

In my experience it has taken 10-20 minutes for a Global Table to be created.